# Alternative infinite summations that equal $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, big-list

Everyone (and I mean everyone) knows this sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} =e$$
Are there any lesser known infinite sums that go to e?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e#As_an_infinite_series

Comment: You should have posted it as an answer. I would have favorited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check here, maybe it is what you want : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e

Answer (score 0):

I know this one because of Stirling's formula:

$e = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** See [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula) for [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).